# Inconsistent error using template functions

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates

(This question has bounty for anyone willing to take a shot)

Hi I have defined overloading template function with container class as arguments

(Here CntrlCls1 = [RWTValOrderedVector](http://www2.roguewave.com/support/docs/hppdocs/tlsref/rwtvalorderedvector.html) and CntrlCls2 = [RWTPtrSortedVector](http://www.nd.edu/~hpcc/solaris_opt/SUNWspro/WS6U2/lib/locale/C/html/manuals/tools++/tlsref/appendix/TPt_9895.htm))

```
template<Class X> void func(CntrCls1<X>* ){}

template<Class X> void func(CntrCls1<X*>* ){}

template<Class X> void func(CntrCls2<X>*){}
```

After defining I am calling function as following

```
func(&ABC);
```

where ABC is instance of type **CntrCls1<*>** (i.e. it is a container of pointers)

Now this is compiling just fine on my computer, but when I compile on a different system, for some reason the compiler is trying to instantiate function template with CntrlCls2 parameter, and as a result giving error.

CtrCls1 and CtrCls2 are unrelated containers.

Update: I am using the VS 2008 to build on both the systems so that shouldn't be a problem.

Update1: I tried to recompile after commenting out function template with CtrCls2 parameter Now the compile is trying to instantiate the first function ( i.e. without pointers) :-(

Comment: Can you provide some more details?  What compilers are you using?  What error messages are you getting?

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: Could you please post more details about `CntrCls1` and `CntrCls2`?

Comment: Why don't you put together the smallest example program you can that actually demonstrates the error, and then list the exact compiler message?

Comment: @Vlad and @template Updated the question with additional info. Basically I am using the same compiler (VS 2008) and using roguewave containers

Comment: @Gaurav: could it possibly be that on the second computer the types are actually the same (one is typedefed to another)? Or one is derived from other? (I've got no experience with roguewave containers.)

Comment: @Tony The error I am getting on compiler won't help basically CntrlCls2 requires its element class to overload comparison operator (i.e. <)  which is not the case thus giving the compiler error but the basic problem is incorrect instantiation of the template function.

Comment: @Vlad I checked for that but to best of my knowledge they are unrelated :-(

Comment: Are the compiling parameters exactly the same?

Comment: Seems to be working on g++: http://www.ideone.com/ETVjw Do `Class` (instead of `class`) in templates declaration is a typo?

Comment: Try explicitly castin &ABC to `CntrCls1<*>` before calling the function, to verify that it really is that type.  If that fails, try doing a make-clean on both boxes and rebuilding.

Comment: @Brent I tried casting it but the result was same.

Comment: In VS2008, check in the about dialog that they are exactly the same build number. VS2008 has service packs that fixes compiler bugs.

Comment: have you checked #include paths? or maybe there is some #if that excludes the second overload from compilation... You can also try to enable "Preprocess to a file" to see what the compiler is really trying to compile

Comment: Please provide an *entire* minimal code snippet that reproduces the problem you're having.  Until you do that, we're all just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check Service Packs for the VS 2008 installed. Compilator versions can differ on machies, causing different results.

2) Try to use a "typename" keyword instead of "class" in template declaration.

And by the way. From the code i see you're using pointers for values of the **sorted** container. Sorted containers expects to find the comparison like

```
template<T> bool operator<(const T&left, const T&right);
```

Since RWTValOrderedVector and RWTPtrSortedVector looks like containers that contains values in sorted orded they should use such comparison operator. BUT, for pointer types operator<  function compares their adresses, not the object they point.
So storing pointers in ordered container will give you sorted pointers set, not the set of the pointers to sorted objects. 
Just FYI.